# Reduce redundancy codes of overload function(const& vs &)

Tags: c++

```
template<typename T, typename TriFunc>
TriFunc process_three_continuous_channels_impl(cv::Mat &input, TriFunc func)
{
    int const total = input.total();
    auto *input_ptr = input.ptr<T>(0);
    for(int index = 0; index != total; ++index){
        func(*input_ptr, *(input_ptr + 1), *(input_ptr + 2));
        input_ptr += 3;
    }

    return func;
}

/**
 * overload, haven't find a good solution to reduce redundancy codes yet
 */
template<typename T, typename TriFunc>
TriFunc process_three_continuous_channels_impl(cv::Mat const &input, TriFunc func)
{       
    int const total = input.total();
    auto const *input_ptr = input.ptr<T>(0);
    for(int index = 0; index != total; ++index){
        func(*input_ptr, *(input_ptr + 1), *(input_ptr + 2));
        input_ptr += 3;
    }

    return func;
}
```

I want to reduce the redundancy codes but can't find a good solution

```
template<typename T, typename TriFunc>
TriFunc process_three_continuous_channels_impl(cv::Mat const &input, TriFunc func)
{
   return process_three_continuous_channels_impl<T>(const_cast<cv::Mat&>(input, func));
}
```

This can't work, since the func would be able to alter the data of input after const_cast
cast the non-const cv::Mat to const can't work either, that way the func wouldn't be able
to alter the data of input. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to do it the other way? Call the 'const' from the 'non-const' one?

Comment: I tried it already, this can't work, because the functor "func" will become unable to alter the data of the "input".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the `cv::Mat` argument be a reference to a template argument type.

```
template<typename Mat, typename T, typename TriFunc>
TriFunc process_three_continuous_channels_impl(Mat&& input, TriFunc func)
{
    int const total = std::forward<Mat>(input).total();
    auto input_ptr = std::forward<Mat>(input).template ptr<T>(0);
    for(int index = 0; index != total; ++index){
        func(*input_ptr, *(input_ptr + 1), *(input_ptr + 2));
        input_ptr += 3;
    }

    return func;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well for me, but there are some details need to fix. .ptr<T> should be .template ptr<T>.

Comment: I find out something, the std::forward<Mat> should be able to remove, because the std::forward would add & or do nothing, it wouln't affect the constness of the input.Please correct me if I am woring

Comment: @StereoMatching: It won't affect constness, but it could affect lvalue or rvalueness. If this isn't important to you, then feel free to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

If C++11 is an option for you then perfect forwarding works here:

```
template <typename T, typename TriFunc>
TriFunc wrapper(cv::Mat && input, TriFunc func)
{
    return process_three_continuous_channels_impl<T>(
        std::forward(input), func);
}
```

Comment: C++11 is an option for me, but I don't know how could this solve the problem?Even the std::forward could recognize the input is "const &" or "&", I still need two different imlementation for "process_three_continuous_channels"